# BandClientManager not returning Band Instance info

Tags: visual-studio, win-universal-app, microsoft-band

I'm creating a windows 10 UWP app with the Band SDK. Bluetooth capability enabled and I can see that my Band 2 is connected in the device blue tooth settings.

I'm always getting the value for bandinfo is "null".

```cs
var bandinfo = (await
    BandClientManager.Instance.GetBandsAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated ! Thanks !

Comment: did you activate your band with Health app? does Health app works with your band properly? Did you add Proximity to app's manifiest?

Comment: did you activate your band with Health app? YES does Health app works with your band properly? YES Did you add Proximity to app's manifiest? YES and Bluetooth. Any idea why its happening ? have you tried this with Band2 ?

Comment: I'm had successfully connected Band 2 from my UWP app using this code:
    var pairedBands = await BandClientManager.Instance.GetBandsAsync();
    
    if (pairedBands.Count() > 0)
       var bandClient = await BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(pairedBands[0]))

Comment: Are you running your app on mobile device? If yes did you installed W10M build 14283 (lates build from Fast Ring)?

Comment: Thank you. I'm running in windows 10 PC build is 10586.

Comment: You want to get the `BandClient` first: 

`pairedBands = await BandClientManager.Instance.GetBandsAsync();`

Then use the `BandClient` to get the individual Band(s):

`bandClient = await BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(pairedBands[0]);`